# Adding pop-up modal on page load to Salesforce CMS page not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, modal, experience-builder-page

I'm trying to create a modal that pops up on page load and have the following in a Codepen, which works properly, but in Experience Builder, it's not working. In an "HTML Editor" component, I have the following:

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

In "Edit CSS", I have the following:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And in "Settings > Advanced > Edit Head Markup", I have this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  console.log("Load modal");

  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    console.log("Click modal");
  };

  span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };

  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
};
</script>
```

However, I can't get it to work and I'm wondering if I have the JavaScript in the wrong place. What do I have wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not creating this as an actual component and trying to achieve this with an HTML component and the site header? This isn't how I'd expect to solve this kind of problem within an Experience Site, and if you're doing anything more than just displaying content in the modal you're going to struggle to achieve that with this approach.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich - There are many reasons, including that I'm just designing something and adding my CSS and another developer will take it from there. However, the more I tinker with this, the more interesting it's becoming, which brings up the following question. Where can I go to learn how to build a component that displays a modal as I've described, so that I'm developing in Salesforce Builder the right way?